# Which whois servers does this library use and are they rate limited?

Tags: whois-ruby

I can't seem to locate which whois servers this library uses, where in the code does it have the URL of the server(s) it connects too?

I'm not sure I understand how whois actually works, but I am assuming it connects to popular registrars API's correct?

Does this mean that if I try and run a whois for thousands of entries I will be rate limited and the response will begin to fail?

Answer (score 2):

The WHOIS server definition list is available at
https://github.com/weppos/whois/blob/master/data/tld.json

It doesn't connect to *popular registrars API*, instead the WHOIS itself is a protocol and the library connects to the WHOIS interfaces provides by registries, whenever applicable.

Each registry has custom rate limiting rules. However, if you perform a large amount of requests, there is an high change you will start being rate limited.

Comment: How do those paid whois services get around rate limiting then?